# How can I change the value of a global variable in React?

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to change the value of a global variable inside React functions but I failed. Can somebody tell me why and how to make aaa "ABC", thanks a lot.

Here's the code:

```
var aaa = 123;

var MyValue = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        aaa = "ABC";
        return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyValue title={aaa} />, //still 123
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: The global variable does change. The problem is that you're not re-rendering the component. Have a look into React's `state` properties.

Answer (score 4):

### Your issue

There are many problems with what you're trying to do here. Like @JamesDonnelly said, you need to look into how React `state` and `prop` works.

It also seems like you misunderstand how the flow of the code works.

```
var aaa = 123;
```

Definition of your `aaa` variable.

```
var MyValue = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        aaa = "ABC";
        return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>;
    }
});
```

Definition of a function that you bind to the variable `MyValue` - it's important to understand here that you **are not** executing the function, you're only defining it.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyValue title={aaa} />, //still 123
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here's where you render your component and your above function is run.

Since this is the flow of the code, your assignment `aaa = "ABC"` happens **after** you've called the render of the `MyValue` component which you pass the `title` prop the value of `aaa` (which is still 123).

This can be demonstrated by the code below. The same exact code yields different values when applied twice. Again, this is because after the first run, you changed the value of `aaa`, hence why the result is different on the next run.

```js
var aaa = 123;

var MyValue = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        aaa = "ABC";
        return <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>;
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyValue title={aaa} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyValue title={aaa} />,
    document.getElementById('container2')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

---

### How to fix

It's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, and why you are changing the value. However, you might want to look into React states and props. There's a guide on the official page that might be useful to you [**Thinking in React**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html). Also check out [**setState()**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no reason to use react this way but [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/61248/) is something that can be closest to what you want but also very hacky.

```js
var MyValue = (function () {
    var mountedInstance;
    var aaa = 123;

    var MyValueInner = React.createClass({
     componentDidMount() {
           mountedInstance = this;
        },
        render: function(){
          return <h1>{aaa}</h1>;
        },
  
    });
    
    MyValueInner.updateAAA = function (aaaNew) {
        aaa = aaaNew;
        mountedInstance.forceUpdate();
    }
    return MyValueInner;
})();

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyValue />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);

MyValue.updateAAA("ABC")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

You can't mutate props inside a component since [All React components must act like pure functions with respect to their props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). If you want to access some global state outside of your component you should go for solutions like redux or flux. They listen on global state or store and force components to render in case of a change.